# O codigo está certo, mas alguem poderia me dizer como funciona detalhadamente o True e False nessa questão (passo-a-passo)?

Tags: python, array

"Faça um programa que, no momento de preencher uma lista com 8 números inteiros, já os armazene de forma crescente. Mostre a lista resultante cada vez que um valor for armazenado"

```
 lista = []

for x in range(8):
    n = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))

    inseriu = False
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if n<lista[i]:
            lista.insert(i, n)
            inseriu = True
            break

    if not inseriu:
        lista.append(n)

    print(lista)
```

Comment: De onde você tirou o código? Se não o entendeu, presumo que não foi você que o desenvolveu.

Comment: aparentemente, essa variável inseriu, será True se o elemento já foi inserido na lista, e False se ele for o último da lista. dessa forma se ele é o último elemento, será colocado por útilmo.

Answer (score 0):

O se bem entendi você quer saber como funciona o True e False certo?

O funcionamento é o seguinte:

```
lista = [] #sua lista não tem nada.
for i in range(8):
    n = int(input("digite um número")
    inserido = False #Variavel para saber se já tem números na lista
    for j in range(len(lista)): # lista ainda não tem nada portanto esse loop não será executado.
        if n < lista[j]:
            lista.insert(i ,n)
            inserido = True
    if not  inserido: #por não ter entrado no loop anterior inserido será False e o contrário True por causa do not
        lista.append(n)
```

> Explicação: a variável inserido serve para saber se já tem alguma coisa na lista.
>   só que para dar uma complicada no código o programa executa ao contrário.
>
> o código séria a mesma coisa se a variável inserido já fosse `True` e passe a ser `False` no momento da arrumação dos tamanhos e o último `if` não poderia ter o `not`